# $N$-body gravitation simulation in 2D and 3D

Tags: newtonian-gravity, computational-physics, simulations

My question is quite general.

I want to make $N$-body simulation, for example galactic dynamics, using $N$ stars.

One possibility is to make these calculations in 2D using an inverse square law and brute force at the beginning.

But I wonder if it is correct to apply these 2D results as if the simulation were done in 3D.

I am not sure because Poisson equation in 2D gives an inverse law and not an inverse square law. This is important because to get for example a closed orbit, I think you need an inverse law in 2D.

Is there somebody having yet this kind of experience?

@All Thank you for your first answers .

In fact, I would like to simulate Galactic Dynamic in 2D to study the famous flat rotation curve. I know about the ellipsoid of velocities from Vlasov equation. But what happens if I try to exploit this equation in 2D ? It sounds for me  like studying a gas in a sheet of paper , and looks unphysical for me, but is it really ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you are considering 2D?

Comment: Almost certainly depends on what you want to simulate. For instance, just getting some mean orbital velocities or periods, using 2D is just fine. If you are trying to do something more complex like colliding galaxies, then 3D is certainly required.

Comment: @ Marius and Kyle : I made a precision in my question

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to model anything close to a realistic scenario then you will need model motions in three dimensions. Even within the solar system, the orbits of the planets have inclinations that cover a range of about $6$ degrees - and that is before you even include minor planets, moons or comets.

Comment: If your N stars are in one plane ans move in it in the beginning, they would stay there and the quadratic law applies, So if it is just for a computer game, its ok, if it should have to do in reality see gandalfs  comment.

Comment: @Gandalf I added a precision in my question . Do you think it is hopeless to study the galactic rotation curve in 2D ? Why , please ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are making a two-dimensional approximation of a flattened system of pointlike masses, like a galactic disk or a star system, then the force law between these masses is inverse-square with distance.

If your two-dimensional simulation is intended to represent the dynamics of long columns of mass oriented in the same direction, as might be suitable for studying e.g. the formation of a cosmic filament, then the force law between these "strings" of mass is inverse-linear with distance.

Comment: @ Sten  Thank you . Do you have some examples or publications about 2D simulation of a galactic disk to study the rotation curve ?